# Embed Swiffy file into wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, google-swiffy

I have converted a SWF banner to HTML5 using Swiffy.
How can I embed it in a post? Moreover, I have several banner sizes, how can I make it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

Go to  https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/upload Then upload swf file . You can download by pressing "ctrl + S"

You can use javascript or media queries (css) for checking device width.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't answer the question 'how to insert swiffy output into a wordpress post'

Answer (score 0):

When using the [HTML Swiffy Insert Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html5-swiffy-insert/) you might want to check out this post:
http://itekblog.com/fix-wordpress-plugin-html5-swiffy-insert/

However, I haven't tried the steps mentioned there went with their own plugin instead:

**ER Swiffy Insert**

- Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/er-swiffy-insert/
- Documentation: http://itekblog.com/wordpress-plugins/er-swiffy-insert/

I used the [online Swiffy converter](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/upload) and downloaded the output, which included a `runtime.js`. Make sure to open it and check the version on line 4, mine was `Swiffy runtime version 7.4.1`.

Use that version in the shortcode as described in the documentation linked above. I'm on wordpress 4.5 and using the shortcode `[swiffy n="1" w="700" h="300" v="7.4.1"]` worked for me. Using a version that's different from the one in the `runtime.js` you downloaded may result in nothing being displayed.

Paste your Swiffy code into a custom field named `swiffy_1`.

Minor caveat: contrary to the documentation – which obviously was written for Swiffy 5.x, not 7.x – my Swiffy code starts with `swiffyobject = {"as3":false,"frameRate":25,"frameCount":1...`